# Exception thrown during test, leads to Item has already been added in dictionary

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, asp.net-membership

Im trying to execute this test method but it throws an exception. AS I step through the code to try to isolate the exception it leads me to:

```
public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
```

shown below the test method. The exception is thrown here with the following message

```
"Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'john'  Key being added: 'john'".
```

Im not sure where to go from here. Can someone point me in the right direction? Also my test method is still in work, so if you see any errors, unless the errors directly cause the exception to be thrown, please overlook them.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFindUsersByName()// filed a bug in TFS
    {
        try
        {

            //set test to create user 
            MembershipProvider prov = this.GetMembershipProvider();
            MembershipCreateStatus status;
            //creates users
            MembershipUser user1 = prov.CreateUser("johnUser1", "12345", "johnUser1@asc.edu", "", "", true, null, out status);
            MembershipUser user2 = prov.CreateUser("johnUser2", "12345", "johnUser2@asc.edu", "", "", true, null, out status);

            //gets users
            user1 = prov.GetUser("johnUser1", false); //not checking if user is online. Argument should be false. Not yet implemented 
            user2 = prov.GetUser("johnUser2", false);

            int pageSize = 5;
            int pageIndex = 0;
            int totalRecords = 5;

            MembershipUserCollection coll = prov.FindUsersByName("john", pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);

            Assert.AreEqual(1, coll.Count);

            List<string> usernames = new List<string>();

            foreach (MembershipUser user in coll)
            {
                usernames.Add(user.UserName);

            }

            Assert.IsNotNull(usernames);
            //Assert.IsTrue(usernames.Contains("john"));


            //Deletes Users
            prov.DeleteUser("johnUser1", true);
            prov.DeleteUser("johnUser2", true);

            //Tries to get users again
            user1 = prov.GetUser("johnUser1", false);
            user2 = prov.GetUser("johnUser2", false);

            //test that no users are returned
            Assert.AreEqual(null, user1);
            Assert.AreEqual(null, user2);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(ex);
            Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
        }
    }


 // MembershipProvider.FindUsersByName       
    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        MembershipUserCollection users = new MembershipUserCollection();

        try
        {
            Profile.MembershipMapper memberMapper = new MembershipMapper();
            List<Profile.Membership> recs = (List<Profile.Membership>)memberMapper.GetMembershipsByUsername(_memberUtil.GetApplicationId(), usernameToMatch, pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);

            foreach (Profile.Membership rec in recs)
            {
                users.Add(GetUserFromModel(rec, usernameToMatch));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception e = CheckEventLog(ex, "FindUsersByName");
            throw e;
        }

        return users;
    }


 private MembershipUser GetUserFromModel(Profile.Membership membership, string username)
    {
        MembershipUser u = new MembershipUser(this.Name, 
            username,
            membership.userId,
            membership.email,
            "",
            "",
            true,
            false,
            this.GetDate(membership.createDate),
            this.GetDate(membership.lastLoginDate),
            this.GetDate(null),
            this.GetDate(membership.lastPasswordChangedDate),
            this.GetDate(null));

        return u;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for GetUserFromModel()?

Comment: its added to the bottom of the code

Comment: I have updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Can you how the GetUserFromModel() should be? Also in my DB it creates johnUser1 and johnUser2. I dont see any users created as John.

Comment: Does Profile.Membership have a userName property? If it does then you should use that instead of username. 
The username parameter is the username you are searching on. It is also the username that is being given to the MembershipUser that is being returned by GetUserFromModel.

Comment: Im looking into it now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store multiple users with the same name in a MembershipUserCollection. 
It is indexed by user name and so prevents you from adding multiple MembershipUsers per name.

The problem is in the GetUserFromModel() method. It is using the search name as the name of the user, because it is finding 2 users with 'john' in their names it is creating 2 users with the username 'john'. It should perhaps use their original username instead of the partial username that was used to search.

Comment: Im adding 2 users, johnUser1 and johnUser2. Im searching for all users with "John" in the username

Comment: Is GetUserFromModel returning the correct MembershipUser? Somehow, MemberShipUserCollection.Add() is being called twice with the same name.

Comment: Additionally, is MembershipMapper returning duplicates?

Comment: Yes it is. And I believe youre correct about being called twice with the same name. Im just not sure why or how its doing this.

Comment: As I step through my code "users.Add(GetUserFromModel(rec, usernameToMatch));" cycle through twice. I assume it does this once for each user being added.

Comment: set a breakpoint on users.Add(GetUserFromModel(rec, usernameToMatch)); and see how many times it is being called, and also check which users are being passed in as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

If any of your membership provider objects are static or a shared reference, and you're adding the "john" user in multiple tests, then you have a race condition as tests are executed in parallel/multithreaded. To resolve, you'll have to either configure a test setup/teardown that clears the data structures per test, and execute them sequentially, or wrap these objects in a custom object programmed to an interface that you can mock.

Comment: I thought about multiple users with the same name "John". However "John" is unique for this test. The information for "John" gets added to the data base followed by the error message I get. Should I still use the suggested resolution?

Comment: Your unit tests should **NOT** be modifying your database!! You need to mock the security objects and "spoof" the responses in the manner that you desire, NOT depend on the DB for testing!

Comment: Im new to testing and came into this project well after it was started. This database was set up exclusively for testing. I have read that using mocking should be done, but for the time being I am working with what I was given. any other suggestions on how to resolve this issue Im having?

Comment: The table begins clear of all users with "John" in the username, however it is not completely cleared. I remove the records added for user John and try again. I get the same error

Comment: There MUST be bug in your workflow or logic, for this situation to be happening. Keep looking.